# fbalbumData holds null in order of retrieving Facebook user album using PHP SDK

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make a website in which users and login into facebook and can see their albums in the website.

For this i created a test user because i still hadn't gave the site for review and from the test user i had an access token and user id which i used in this code.

But fbAlbumData returns empty for some reason whereas fbAlbumObj from where it is retrieving data is not empty and this is bugging me for days. Please help.

Here's my index.php

```
<?php
session_start();


require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '',
  'app_secret' => '',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
  ]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email']; // optional

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = 'EAAEqYQ3zkO0BAJ72W4BggUODSv4frv1xNfX72nnvRSDSdM7BZAlLezQG0q3MYdGWA0HZCH1lgaZBVkFcXNxPM9Xk8bRelcx9yviVBXfexPF4qog8ZCSqPmiYtNVEQ1tmrSZAHi04myKYUo3ZCkMsEZA3F7d7sxo7jsY8z7NFz5jYXdi9AoOH48u8NItZARFLWBQBsvZBRT9y20x5fnG9jZBIV8n2G1tFYAVeSHNR4ZBFyuX5EGDtemNbzFC';
    } else {
        $appId = '';
        $appSecret = '';
        $graphActLink = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={$appId}&client_secret={$appSecret}&grant_type=client_credentials";

    // Retrieve access token
        $accessTokenJson = file_get_contents($graphActLink);
        $accessTokenObj = json_decode($accessTokenJson);
        $access_token = 'EAAEqYQ3zkO0BAJ72W4BggUODSv4frv1xNfX72nnvRSDSdM7BZAlLezQG0q3MYdGWA0HZCH1lgaZBVkFcXNxPM9Xk8bRelcx9yviVBXfexPF4qog8ZCSqPmiYtNVEQ1tmrSZAHi04myKYUo3ZCkMsEZA3F7d7sxo7jsY8z7NFz5jYXdi9AoOH48u8NItZARFLWBQBsvZBRT9y20x5fnG9jZBIV8n2G1tFYAVeSHNR4ZBFyuX5EGDtemNbzFC';

        $accessToken = 'EAAEqYQ3zkO0BAJ72W4BggUODSv4frv1xNfX72nnvRSDSdM7BZAlLezQG0q3MYdGWA0HZCH1lgaZBVkFcXNxPM9Xk8bRelcx9yviVBXfexPF4qog8ZCSqPmiYtNVEQ1tmrSZAHi04myKYUo3ZCkMsEZA3F7d7sxo7jsY8z7NFz5jYXdi9AoOH48u8NItZARFLWBQBsvZBRT9y20x5fnG9jZBIV8n2G1tFYAVeSHNR4ZBFyuX5EGDtemNbzFC';
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = $access_token;

    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }
if (isset($accessToken)) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        // getting short-lived access token
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
        // setting default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }
    // redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        header('Location: ./');
    }
    // getting basic info about user
    try {

        $fields="id,name,description,link,cover_photo,count";
        $fb_page_id = '104496290269987';
        $graphAlbLink = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{$fb_page_id}/albums?fields={$fields}&access_token={$accessToken}";

        $jsonData = file_get_contents($graphAlbLink);
        $fbAlbumObj = json_decode($jsonData, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
        $fbAlbumData = $fbAlbumObj['data'];

        if($fbAlbumData == NULL)
        {
            echo "null";
        }

    foreach($fbAlbumData as $data){


    $id = isset($data['id'])?$data['id']:'';
    $name = isset($data['name'])?$data['name']:'';
    $description = isset($data['description'])?$data['description']:'';
    $link = isset($data['link'])?$data['link']:'';
    $cover_photo_id = isset($data['cover_photo']['id'])?$data['cover_photo']['id']:'';
    $count = isset($data['count'])?$data['count']:'';

    $pictureLink = "photos.php?album_id={$id}&album_name={$name}";
    echo "<div class='fb-album'>";
    echo "<a href='{$pictureLink}'>";
    echo "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{$cover_photo_id}/picture?access_token={$access_token}' alt=''>";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "<h3>{$name}</h3>";

    $photoCount = ($count > 1)?$count. 'Photos':$count. 'Photo';

    echo "<p><span style='color:#888;'>{$photoCount} / <a href='{$link}' target='_blank'>View on Facebook</a></span></p>";
    echo "<p>{$description}</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    }



    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        session_destroy();
        // redirecting user back to app login page
        header("Location: ./");
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validatio   n fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // printing $profile array on the screen which holds the basic info about user








    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
    // replace your website URL same as added in the developers.facebook.com/apps e.g. if you used http instead of https and you used non-www version or www version of your website then you must add the same here
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/fb_rt/index.php', $permissions);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you are not even asking the user for the relevant permission to access their photos ...